# How to perform arithmetic operation on a date in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7

I have a date column in csv file say `Date` having dates in this format `04/21/2013` and I have one more column `Next_Day`. In `Next_Day` column I want to populate the date which comes immediately after the date mentioned in date column. For eg. if date column has `04/21/2013` as date then I want `04/22/2013` in Next_Day column.

We can use `+1` in excel but I don't know how to perform this in Python.

Please help me in resolving this.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Using [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)

```
>>> import datetime
>>> s = '04/21/2013'
>>> d = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%m/%d/%Y') + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
>>> print(d.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
04/22/2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as a one-liner. Prints 1 day 1 hour & 30 minutes ago from now:

```
python -c 'import datetime;print(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1,hours=1,minutes=30))'

2022-02-08 13:11:06.304608
```